# Do synonyms work in Dynamics SL (Solomon)?

Tags: sql-server, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-sl

A client has a highly customized SL 2011 FP1 installation with numerous table names starting with "x". They would like to move these custom tables to either a different database or different schema (long story). I originally thought we could use synonyms for this -- simply move a given table and create a synonym pointing to its new location.

But when I try doing this with one table, call it `xCustomTable`, I get an error in the `DbNav` property (where the query is a simple `SELECT * FROM xCustomTable WHERE CustomField LIKE @parm1`).

This seems to indicate the synonym is not working within SL. But I don't understand why.

Does anyone know if it's even possible to use synonyms with SL?

Comment: What is the error message? How is the synonym defined?

Comment: The error is a System Message 5005: "Unable to locate field <CustomFieldName> in table <xCustomTable>. Error in property Dbnav of control Form1.spread1." The synonym definition is "CREATE SYNONYM [dbo].[xCustomTable] FOR [NewTestSchema].[xCustomTable]."

Comment: Sounds like dynamics may be trying to outsmart you and trying to derive metadata for the table under dbo, and not finding any. Maybe you could try a view instead of a synonym? Not as tidy, but with some of these products you have to compromise.

Comment: Thanks, I did try a view and that approach does work.